# Can't get output from console process

Tags: c#

This code works well with ipconfig.exe, but i get nothing with my target app.

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "miner.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = command;
p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

p.OutputDataReceived += OutputDataReceived;
p.ErrorDataReceived += ErrorDataReceived;

p.Start();
p.BeginOutputReadLine();
p.StandardInput.Close();
```

Can anybody tell what may be wrong and what can i do? Target app is written in c++ and i think uses printf for output. On forum i saw guy saying that he can't get this app work with pipes in linux.

Comment: Is the C++ program supposed to write something on console? If yes comment out the CreateNoWindow line and try again

Comment: if run normally (by hand) it shows textlines running in console window

Comment: you have written p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow=true and p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;... so no console window is getting created

Comment: @Taleeb, no it does nothing, i only get once "null" when i close the window.

Answer (score 0):

Code look fine.

If process does not output anything to standard output you'd not be able to capture anything.

You can verify that it is program's behavior and not bug in you code by using existing output redirect on Windows or piping output to some other program Windows/*nix -

```
tool.exe > output.txt  
tool.exe | more
```

Comment: Tested it, file is created, but nothing in it. But if i run app normaly, i see text in window! There should be the way to get this text out)))